# Where/How to store text, if not in kill-ring/registers [elisp, emacs]

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to be able to store text between 2 positions (the string in between), but I don't know where to conveniently store it, perhaps just locally, or even globally (`let` or `setq`). The answer is probably out there, but I couldn't find it.

Example:

I would like to store text in a symbol in order to search for it backwards. Let's say the region from (point) until the first whitespace character.

My previous way of doing this was using (kill-ring-save), but I know this is a bad practice.

From (here) `(message "hello")`(point)

I would be interested in both better techniques for doing this, as well as the best way to store a string which is somehwere around `(point)`.

Comment: Hmmm.  You already mentioned `let`.  How is `let` now solving this for you?  Maybe an example of how you currently use the kill-ring would lead to a clearer answer.

Comment: Can you use registers? M-x copy-to-register or C-x r s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a temporary local scope is all you require, then you definitely want to use `let`.

Otherwise you would usually define a variable (keeping in mind when you name it that elisp has no name spaces, so best practice is to use as reliably unique a prefix for all symbol names in a given library as practical).

```
(defvar SYMBOL &optional INITVALUE DOCSTRING)
```

If you omit the INITVALUE argument, the variable will not be bound initially, but ensures that your variable will use dynamic binding once used.

Then you just `setq` the variable as required.

**Edit:**
To obtain a buffer's contents between two points, use either of

- `(buffer-substring START END)`
- `(buffer-substring-no-properties START END)`

depending on whether or not you wish to preserve text properties.

Comment: But how do we give it to hold the value of a  string, e.g. that is found when we want to save the text between (point) and the thing searched back (i.e. [^a-z])?

Comment: Is that the dynamic binding you are talking about?

Comment: Dynamic binding is the default scoping mechanism in Emacs. See `C-h i g (elisp) Variable Scoping RET`. You don't really need to worry about it, other than noting that it is best practice to `defvar` your variables before you set them.

Comment: I've edited my answer regarding how obtain the string between two points in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The regular no-frills answer would be to just use `let`.  Contrary to what you seem to believe, it does not allocate global storage.  In fact, it does just the opposite.

```
(let ((myvalue "temporary string"))
  (message myvalue) )
=> "temporary string"

myvalue
=> Lisp error: (void-variable myvalue)
```

And you can easily write a function with a variable whose value is set only during the function's execution.  The `interactive` form allows you to easily obtain the values of point and mark.

```
(defun mysearch (point mark)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties point mark))
    (message "your search for %s can commence ..." str) ) )
```

A common idiom is to use `save-excursion` to move point to another place, then grab the region between the original location and where you ended up, then do something with it.  When you exit the `save-excursion`, the cursor's position (and several other things) will be restored to how they were before.

```
(defun mysearch ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((here (point)) str)
      (forward-word -1)
      (setq str (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) here))
      (message "your search for %s can commence ..." str) ) ) )
```

Perhaps you also want to look at http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_idioms.html

If you need to persist the value between function invocations, then the common thing to do is to `defvar` a variable like @phils suggests.  Several variables with a common prefix sounds like you should be creating a separate module for yourself.  For a flexible solution with low namespace footprint, create your own `obarray` (and achieve some sort of guru status).  See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#Definition%20of%20mapatoms